# JavaScript Appending to a Document

Tags: javascript, append, dom-events

The goal is to be able to click on one of the items and see the description and cost below it. This should be done dynamically. Here is what I have so far:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html> 
    <head> Assignment 4B 

    <div id="first" onclick="displayFirst()"> Cleanser </div>
    <div id ="second" onclick="displaySecond()"> Exfoliator </div>
    <div id ="third" onclick="displayThird()"> Toner </div>
    <div id ="fourth" onclick="displayFourth()"> Moisturizer </div>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    
    function displayFirst()
    {
     var d1=document.getElementByID("first");
     var text=document.createTextNode("description: will cleanse the face and cost: $20");
     d1.appendChild(text);
    }
    var d2 = document.getElementByID("second");
    function displaySecond()
    {
     var d2=document.getElementByID("second");
     var text=document.createTextNode("description: will exfoliate the face and cost: $30");
     d1.appendChild(text);
    }
    var d3 = document.getElementByID("third");
    function displayThird()
    {
     var d1=document.getElementByID("first");
     var text=document.createTextNode("description: will toner the face and cost: $15");
     d1.appendChild(text);
    }
    var d4 = document.getElementByID("fourth");
    function displayFourth()
    {
     var d1=document.getElementByID("first");
     var text=document.createTextNode("description: will moisturize the face and cost: $50");
     d1.appendChild(text);
    }
    
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I am able to create the textNode and append it but when I click on the actual item nothing happens. I am not sure if I need to print something out inside each function to get it to display.

Comment: can you make a fiddle? Any debug info? any error in console??

Comment: change `document.getElementByID` to `document.getElementById`, javascript is case-sensitive. [Using the web console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) is the good habit when develop web app.

Comment: Yes that was it!! Thank you so much!